# Configuration.GetSection возвращает null, хотя данные в конфигурации есть

Tags: c#, configuration

Есть вот такой незатейливый код:

```
internal class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var host = CreateHost();
        var connectionProvider = ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<ConnectionProvider>(host.Services);
    }

    private static IHost CreateHost() =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
        .ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
        {
            var ccs = context.Configuration.GetSection("Connection");
            services.Configure<ConnectionOptions>(context.Configuration.GetSection("Connection"));
            services.AddSingleton<ConnectionProvider>();
            services.AddSingleton<DataProvider>();
        })
        .Build();
}
```

Определён класс ConnectionOptions, где имена свойств совпадают с именами в appsettings.json
Файл appsettings.json верный, копируется в папку, откуда приложение запускается. Более того, при отладке я вижу, что context.Configuration содержит 4 провайдера, в том числе, и данные из этого файла. JsonConfigurationProvider for 'appsettings.json' помечен в скобочках как Optional. Но context.Configuration.GetSection("Connection") почему-то возвращает значение ccs.Value = null, где должны быть данные из файла конфигурации.
Файл appsettings.json выглядит вот так:

```json
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "Connection": {
    "Uri": "MyUri",
    "Login": "MyLogin",
    "Password": "MyPassword"
  }
}
```

В чём может быть дело? Что не так? Нужно как-то указать дефолтный провайдер конфига?

Comment: Код  в appsettings.json, выглядит правильно.  К чему вы хотели подключиться через эту секцию "Connection" с его парами ключ - значение ? Вы указали ссылку на доступ к секции, может быть, далее нужно настроить ссылки на ключи, что бы получать такие значения?

Comment: Секция через IOptions<Connection> инжектится в конструктор класс ConnectionProvider:
`public ConnectionProvider(IOptions<ConnectionOptions>options
{
     _options = options;
)`
Но в конструктор приходит options, у которого Value = null. И я не могу понять почему так получается.
Кстати, если написать так:

`var ccs = context.Configuration.GetSection("Connection").Get<Connection>();`
то в ccs будут правильные данные из конфигурации.

Comment: Ну я это и имел в виду, что GetSection("Connection") подразумевает доступ к секции в appsettings,  а далее нужно получить значение для ключа то есть дописать Get....И далее указать ключ... Так вы решили проблему?